# Looking for examples of non-singular holomorphic foliations with compact leaves

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, foliations, fibration

I am looking for examples (or what is known about) of the following kind of object:

1. X compact Kähler manifold
2. F a non-singular holomorphic foliation on X (so given by a holomorphic subbundle of the holomorphic tangent bundle of X that is invariant under the Lie bracket)
3. All the leaves of the foliation determined by F are compact

Of course a smooth fibration satisfies these.   I also know of one example (possibly due to Brunella) that is a foliation of a compact surface by curves, that is given as the global quotient of a fibration by a finite group.

So are there more interesting examples known to exist (so not given a a global quotient of a fibration by a finite group)?

Thanks!

Comment: The theory of holomorphic Poisson manifolds might be a good place to look for. The foliation by symplectic leaves is in general singular, but there are still interesting cases where it is non-singular.

Answer (score 2):

They are all fibrations (not necessarily smooth since they may have leaves with non-trivial holonomy).  The result is due to Edwards, Millett and Sullivan and appears in the paper Foliations with all leaves compact published by Topology.

---

**Clarification:** As my usage of the term "fibration" does not seem to be standard, thanks to Moishe Kohan for gracefully pointing that out, let me formulate more precisely what I meant by "They are all fibrations". If all the leaves of a smooth foliation $\mathcal F$ on a compact Kähler manifold $X$ are compact then the leaf space is Hausdorff and  there exists a proper holomorphic map with connected fibers $\pi:X \to Y$ to normal compact complex variety $Y$ with at worst quotient singularities and with set of fibers equal to the set of leaves of $\mathcal F$.

---

I do not know if they are always a quotient of a smooth fibration by a finite group. One case where this is true is when the foliation in question is the symplectic foliation of a constant rank Poisson structure. See https://doi.org/10.2140/gt.2022.26.2831

Comment: What you wrote is simply wrong, or you are using a nonstandard notion of a "fibration."

Comment: @MoisheKohan It's you who are using nonstandard (for algebraic/complex geometry) notion of fibration. Read the theorem first, please, and then proceed to resent it you want.

Comment: @DenisT: Thank you for your suggestion; I guess you will also tell Claire Voisin that her definition in "Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry" is a nonstandard one...